# How to measure GSM signal strength on iPad mini?

Tags: ipad

IPad mini running iOS 6. Trying to find Field Test Mode but so far no dice. Can anyone help? If not available what is the alternative? Cant find any app to do so. Unwilling to jailbreak.

Thanks

Comment: Would you like to edit in a little more about he problem you are trying to solve. What need do you have past the 5 level signal bar that the OS provides?